# Vaadin: Ошибка при деплое на wildfly 20(debian). Как настроить vaadin?

Tags: debian, wildfly, vaadin

Пытаюсь задеплоить spring boot+vaadin 14 приложение на wildfly поставленный на debian. Получаю ошибку - не может записать файл package.json

```
Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:2.0.2.Final:deploy 
(default-cli) on project admin: Failed to execute goal deploy: 
{"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" 
=> {"Operation step-1" => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => 
{"jboss.deployment.unit.\"admin.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: 
File '/home/gitlab-runner/builds/a41nNuzA/0/...../package.json' cannot be written to
```

Куда он пытается его записать? Как настроить vaadin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно запускать в production mode

```
<vaadin.productionMode>true</vaadin.productionMode>
```

И перед этим сделать

```
mvn vaadin:build-frontend
```